# Why didn't Achashveirosh reward Mordechai immediately?

Tags: purim, megillat-esther, reward-punishment

Esther tells Achashveirosh in the name of Mordechai of a plot to assassinate him (Achashveirosh). They investigate, and stop the would-be assassins. And then... nothing? Why didn't Achashveirosh reward Mordechai right then?

Comment: וְשִמְחַת הַמֶּלֶך שָכָחָה

Comment: You know how it is when you're a king -- you're focused on the immediate issue (not getting killed), and you rely on your servants to take care of pesky little details like record-keeping and compensation. :-)  Seriously, though, it's not clear that Achashveirosh knew who reported it until his insomniac night; it may not be that he forgot but that he never knew where the info came from.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, but doesn't the Megillah say that "Esther informed the king in the name of Mordechai" (2:22)?

Comment: @Alex, ah yes, you're right.  But busy kings can be forgetful, especially when the credit comes at the beginning of the matter when it's just a rumor, and at this point in the story it's not clear to me if Esther is anything more than a pretty face to King A.

Comment: @Alex, even so, it is not inconceivable that he was distracted, as were his assistants, especially considering the fact that he was just saved from a plot to kill him. He may not have thought to order a reward/celebration for Mordechai, or even if he did, it may have been forgotten about in the aftermath and (most likely) the ensuing investigation into whether there were more conspirators, and of course meting out punishment (and possible trial, although it's also possible that was not seen as necessary), etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Malbim on Megillas Esther](http://amzn.com/1568711352) (2:23, page 61 in the aforelinked book) asks this question, and concludes that this is one of the numerous miracles surrounding the story of Esther's ascent to power. It would have been much more normal for the debt to have been paid off immediately, and his not doing so is simply an act of G-d.

Comment: If necessary, I can provide an exact quote when I get home later on.

Comment: that would be awesome.

Comment: @Moshe - citation added.

Answer (score 7):

Since Mordechai did not tell the King himself, Achashveirosh felt beholden to Esther for saving his life, and in addition Hashem put into the mind of Achashveirosh not to pay Mordechai right away in order to save it for later when it was needed.

http://www.reader.co.il/article/9626/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%AA%D7%94-%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9-%D7%94%D7%99%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%91-%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A3-%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%9E%D7%9F-

> מרדכי נקרא בלשן, כי הבין שבעים לשון, שכן היה מהסנהדרין שהיו בקיאים
>   בשבעים לשון. מרדכי שמע את כל מה שדיברו ביניהם בגתן ותרש, והוא סיפר
>   לאסתר את מזימתם.
>
> אסתר היתה סבורה שמוטב היה אילו היה מרדכי עצמו מספר את הדבר למלך, כי
>   אסתר אהבה מאד את מרדכי וביקשה את טובתו. אבל אסתר חששה שמא יוודע על כך
>   לבגתן ותרש והם ימהרו להוציא את הארס ולשפוך את המים, וכשיחקור המלך
>   בדבר, לא ימצא כל הוכחה, ואז יבוא מרדכי לכלל סכנה. על כן אמרה היא עצמה
>   את הדבר למלך בשם מרדכי: ''היום בא לכאן מרדכי היהודי, ובין הדברים סיפר
>   לי שנודע לו שבגתן ותרש זוממים להרעילך''. בתחבולה זו לא היה משום סכנה,
>   כיוון שאפילו יבקש אחשורוש ולא ימצא הוכחה, אי אפשר יהיה להאשים את
>   מרדכי, שאז תאמר, שמרדכי לא ראה את הדבר בעיניו. והראיה, שאם היה יודע את
>   הדבר בבירור, לא היה מדבר עם אסתר, אלא הוא עצמו היה נכנס למלך ומודיע
>   לו, אבל מאחר שהיה פקפוק בלבו, סיפר את הדבר לאסתר, שהרי אין לו קרוב
>   יותר מאסתר, והיא תחקור אם יש אמת בדבר ותשמור את המלך.
>
> מרדכי לא התכוון להנקם מבגתן ותרש, אלא להציל את המלך. כיון שלא הודיע
>   מרדכי עצמו את הדבר למלך, לא נתן לו המלך את שכרו מיד, כי היה סבור שלא
>   מרדכי שמר על המלך, אלא אסתר. ואם כן, אסתר היא זו שהיתה ראויה לקבל שכר,
>   שהרי היא הוכיחה נאמנות ולא מרדכי. אבל משהגיע הזמן, לאחר שנהרגו בגתן
>   ותרש, ובאו לכתוב את הדבר בספר הזכרונות, שינתה אסתר את הנוסח, ובמקום
>   לכתוב בשם אסתר כתבה בשם מרדכי, בכך היא חייבה את המלך לשלם למרדכי.
>   התרחש כאן הנס, שנתן הקב''ה בלב המלך שלא לשלם למרדכי שכר באותה שעה, כדי
>   שיזכור את טובתו בשעת מצוקה